# How to make particles appear where I draw weight using dynamic paint?

Tags: particles, weight-painting, dynamic-paint

How to make particles appear where I draw weight using dynamic paint? I know how to do it with hair - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=746GAAZbG_U but this method does not work with particles (or I am doing something wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting workaround, **found by Blenderartists member suboptimal** - http://blenderartists.org/forum/show...inally-working

- First you need to uv unwrap your Canvas and add two dynamic paint
  canvassesses (Whats the plural?)
- The first one is gonna generate the Time Map, the other one the
  Density Map. Make sure you turn of dry and slow because otherwise the
  particles later will behave a bit weird.
- The dissolve time for the Time map canvas must be as long as the
  particles are going to be emitted.

[image]

- Then setup your brush with a white color. You have to use Mesh Volume
  or Particle system with 0 smooth raduis as the paint source (nothing
  with a blurred edge)

[image]

- Then bake your dyn paint image sequences, the frame range must be the
  same as your particle emission frame range.
- Take the last frame of each one of your sequences and fill its
  transparent background with black.
- Add a particle system, it should have a pretty big amount of
  particles. Next step is using them as particle textures, go to the
  texture tab select particle textures ( I think they aren't in cycles
  yet, only in BI). Load the Time Map, mapping to uv etc. and check
  Time in the influence tab.
- Repeat it for the density Map but use Density influence this time.

[image]

Comment: As I understand, this workaround does not work in Cycles (since there is no particle textures in Cycles), and, as I understand, it animates the opacity of the particles, that won't help me, because in my scene particles physically affect other objects in the scene.

Comment: If you mean textures for affecting particles distribution in Cycles then [it is possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnuNbIujpj8), though manual [lacks information about that](https://developer.blender.org/T46363). It works pretty much the same as in Internal.

Comment: @MrZak Thank you for the information! It is strange, that since 2013, when this workaround was written, this feature is still povided for hair, but not provided for particles in Blender.

Comment: @MrZak I started to look for this feature, because I'm making a character coming out of the water. I could use the character as a canvas, and water as a brush for dinamic paint. Then I would set up a system of particles (water drops), so that they flow from the "wet" areas of the character's body and stop to flow, when they are "dry". And this is just one example of how this feature coud be used.